Al actualizar las librerías de jasperreport, aparece el error incompatible types for field columnCount (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport)
Estoy trabajando en netbeans 12 y acabo de actualizar todas mis librerías sobre todos del jasperreports desde la versión 6.0 a la versión 7.0 que mi intención es hacerlo correr bajo Windows 11, así que lo que hice fue eliminar todas las extensiones .jasper de cada reporte y que quede actualizada con la versión actualizada del jasperreports, y me dan este este error:
ago 10, 2024 5:47:36 PM Archivos.Frmpresupuesto cmdimprimirActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from URL:     file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prueba1/build/classes/Archivos/presupuesto3.jasper.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:185)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:165)
at Archivos.Frmpresupuesto.cmdimprimirActionPerformed(Frmpresupuesto.java:2895)
at Archivos.Frmpresupuesto.access$700(Frmpresupuesto.java:52)
at Archivos.Frmpresupuesto$8.actionPerformed(Frmpresupuesto.java:772)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport; incompatible types for field columnCount


at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.matchFields(ObjectStreamClass.java:2468)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getReflector(ObjectStreamClass.java:2362)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2001)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2001)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1665)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:459)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:181)

Este es el código que utilizo para los reportes:
int desicion = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Este Presupuesto es con Mano de Obra C/ Valores y Repuestos C/Valores.?");
            switch (desicion) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                try { 
                    MyConnection cn = new MyConnection();
                    Connection conn = cn.getConnection();
                    JasperReport reporte = null;
                    String path = "src/Archivos/presupuesto3.jasper";
                    Map parametros = new HashMap();
                    parametros.put("patente", txtpatente.getText());
                    reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/Archivos/presupuesto3.jasper"));
                    JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, conn);
                    JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
                    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    view.setVisible(true);
                } catch (JRException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Frmpresupuesto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                try {
                    MyConnection cn = new MyConnection();
                    Connection conn = cn.getConnection();
                    JasperReport reporte = null;
                    String path = "src/Archivos/presupuesto4.jasper";
                    Map parametros = new HashMap();
                    parametros.put("patente", txtpatente.getText());
                    reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/Archivos/presupuesto4.jasper"));
                    JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, conn);
                    JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
                    view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    view.setVisible(true);
                } catch (JRException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Frmpresupuesto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                break;

Ahora, viendo la lista de los errores enunciados anteriormente, esta línea:
reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/Archivos/presupuesto4.jasper"));

Además muestro los import que utilizo actualmente para poder trabajar con los jasperreports (en caso de que me falte alguno favor de indicarme):
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRSaveContributor;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRDocxSaveContributor;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewerToolbar;

Además les informo que estas son las librerías que uso y de las cuales actualice jasperreports-7.0.0, jasperreports-7.0.0-javadoc, jasperreports-fonts-7.0.0, jasperreports-functions-7.0.0 y jasperreports-metadata-7.0.0

¿ "elininar todas las extensiones .jasper" ? ¿Eliminaste la extensión de los nombres de archivo o eliminaste todos los archivos con extensión .jasper? ¿Volviste a compilar los jrxml?.

¿Estás utilizando las dependencias correctas? Revisá la versión de cada biblioteca que tengas.

@Sal muy buenas, mis disculpas por no haberte contestado anteriormente ya que me encontraba con problemas de alud, te cuento que elimine las extensiones Jasper y volví a compilar y sigue con el mismo problema, no lo entiendo, además te cuento que estas son las librerías que actualice para el jasperreports: jasperreports-7.0.0, jasperreports-7.0.0-javadoc, jasperreports-fonts-7.0.0, jasperreports-functions-7.0.0 y jasperreports-metadata-7.0.0, no se si faltara alguna mas

@padaleiana te informo que estas son las librerías que uso y de las cuales actualice  jasperreports-7.0.0, jasperreports-7.0.0-javadoc, jasperreports-fonts-7.0.0, jasperreports-functions-7.0.0 y jasperreports-metadata-7.0.0, como te digo las que me envías en el enlace son las mismas que baje pero no tienen las extensiones .jar

@padaleiana hay lo hice como me mencionaste, ojala que con eso me puedan ayudar, ya que llevo mas de una semana en esto y nadie me ha podido dar una ayuda en concreto, logro sin entender si en Windows 10 funciona todo excelente los reportes hechos en jasperreport pero en el Windows 11 nada de nada no entiendo, mi humilde comentario que no hay herramienta que funcione bien con el Windows 11 es mi humilde comentario, sin enojarse ya que cuando uno hace un comentario como este se enojan pero como no funciona no es culpa mia, sino de los desarrolladores, y se que con esto se van enojar

¿Tenés la completa certeza de que los .jar de las dependencias no están en Maven? Revisé como 4 o 5 dependencias (sí, una por una) y sí aparecían los .jar. De nuevo, revisá que estés utilizando las dependencias correctas, de todas y cada una de las librerías de jasper que has instalado.

@padaleiana te informo y te pido mis disculpas no tengo Maven, lo baje a través de la web, y son las mismas que tenia antes con la versión 6.18, y las he revisado una por una, y lo he hecho varias veces pensando que me había equivocado yo, ya que siempre es culpa mía no de la gente del desarrollo del Jasper, dime que mas puedo hacer para solucionar este problema, dime alguna solucion o no la tienes?

No es necesario que menciones a otros para determinar tu problema. Es más: no entiendo por qué mencionás que "no tenés Maven". Los enlaces a los .jar están en ese repositorio.

Sin Maven ¿usas algún otro constructor de código (ej. Ant o Gradle)?. No es claro si es problema de dependencia, ya que se inicia el JRLoader mas no el JasperFillManager por que no encuentra el .jasper, entonces primero hay que asegurarse que el archivo se encuentre donde debe. Si no usas constructor entonces debemos conocer tu estructura de archivos, ¿dónde se genera el .jasper?.

@Sal no utilizo Maven el jasper lo utilizo en el mismo netbeans ya que el jasper soft studio me da siempre problemas al momento de generar los reportes, y en las librerías utilizo los itext, groovy-all y por ultimo las librerías jasperreport, por las ubicaciones de los archivos están bien, las he revisados mas de 10 veces e incluso hoy día los volví a revisar, les puedo consultar porque siempre dudan de mi palabra, siempre desconfiando, si el error no es mío es de los desabolladores, porque siempre me culpan a mi de todo, ya me aburrí, reviso y reviso y siempre lo mismo.

Hector.. tienes que entender que no se te culpa a vos, pero nadie mas que vos esta en tu pc y tu entorno de desarrollo y ve lo que vos ves. Por mas frustrante que suene, tenes que chequear y re chequear que todo esta bien, porque tal vez, en algun momento, te salteaste algo. No es facil encontrar un error a veces, pero imaginate que toda la gente que te esta contestando no duda de vos, si no que trata de ayudarte a ciegas (porque no puede reproducir tu problema). Asi que tomate las cosas con calma, y acepta la ayuda..

Disculpa. ¿Pudiste resolverlo? Tengo un problema similar. Saludos!

Disculpa. ¿Pudiste resolverlo? Tuve el mismo problema y lo resolví de la siguiente "truculenta" forma. En mi caso, incluí las siguientes bibliotecas en el Classpath:
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
jasperreports-6.7.0.jar
jasperreports-fonts-6.7.0.jar
jasperreports-functions-6.7.0.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-6.7.0.jar
Utilicé ambos "commons-collections" según una sugerencia leída en alguna parte. Por otra parte, esa versión de Jasper Reports me funcionó, pero solo habiendo compilado los archivos ".jasper" con "Jaspersoft Studio 5.6 Final".
Espero sea de ayuda.

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

@Gonzalo Gallegos muy buenas tardes, esperando que te encuentres muy bien, no lo he podido resolver he buscado y buscado, ahora baje otras actualizaciones, pero sigo en las mismas, mira yo tenia esta librería jasperreports-6.18.1 la cual la corría bajo Windows 10, y la actualice a la 7.0 que me recomendaron que interactuaba bien para el Windows 11, si hay me empezaron los problemas con los reportes realizado en jasperreport, pero vuelvo al Windows 10 con la librería antes mencionada y me funciona al 100% los reportes. Como lo mencione anteriormente el problema es cuando lo llevo al Windows 11

Cuando dices q cambiaste de versión, te refieres al jasper studio, o a las librerías? Porque para cambiar de versión debes cambiar los dos q t mencione antes. Además un reporte generado en una versión antigua, por ejemplo uno q hiciste con el 6.0, al cargarlo en el 7.0, no son compatibles, la configuración interna del código es muy distinta x eso puede q te de error. Solución: Haz lo q hice yo. Vuelve a hacer el reporte con la nueva versión instalada. Y aún más: no uses el jasper studio 7.0, tiene bugs con respecto a las variables, usa el 6.21.3 que es la última q funciona sin problemas

te informo que cambie las libreras del jasper del 6.18 a la 7.0.0, por lo cual se supone que es la ultima y que las baje una por una, eso ya lo haba explcados mas de  una vez, siempre dudando de mi palabra, que esto que esto otro, pero no me ayudan en nada de nada

Esta es la zona de respuestas, no de comentarios.
